# What is the generic solution to write data into DB?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I have a `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` `stat` that contains the following data:

```
"Param1", "23"
"Param2", "31.1"
"Param3", "abc"
```

Now I want to save this data into DB, table MY_TAB:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MY_TAB (
  Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  Param1 INT NOT NULL,
  Param2 DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  Param3 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL);
```

I developed the code that can perfectly READ the data from DB, but I am not sure how to efficiently write the data into DB using LinkedHashMap. In particular, I know names of variables, but all the data is saved as String, while in DB Param1, Param2 and Param3 are integer, decimal and varchar, accordingly.

Please notice that I'm searching for a generic solution.

Comment: MySQL is fairly forgiving, some would say to a fault; you should be able to insert string values without error as long as the values "parse" to the type. However, you may or may not (depending on server config) get errors if something like `"Param2","31.1a"` occurs.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Could you give a small example please?

Comment: I'm not a java developer, so I don't know the libraries involved; just saying `INSERT INTO MY_TAB (Param1, Param2, Param3) VALUES ('1', '1.2', 'a3fx_');` should work without any problems.